# Guardar imagen en SQLite Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, imagen, sqlite, xamarin

He desarrollado con xamarin forms mi interfaz con un image y tengo un método para cargar imágenes de la galería y los datos que necesito en cada elemento pero no se como definir el campo para imagen en la tabla de SQLite ni los métodos para guardar y recuperar la imagen en el image.

Esta es mi tabla:

```
[Table("Usuarios")]
public class T_RegistroUsuario
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Contraseña { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es guardarlo como arreglo de bytes.

```
//Clase de la tabla Images(Ejemplo)           

        public byte[] MiImagen{ get; set; }


//Controller

 SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(con);

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images(MiImagen) VALUES (@img)";
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary, data.Length);
            cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = data;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Para leerlas

    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(con);   
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MiImagen FROM Images WHERE Id=1";
                byte[] data = (byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

//Para guardala como variable

Image imagen = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(data));
```